# Using clang-tidy checks to work on multiple files

Tags: clang, clang-tidy

I'm registering new checks in clang-tidy. I was able to create a new check and tried to run it on multiple files. My check verifies if a variable defined in first file is getting redefined in other file as well. If it does then it should throw an error. The check is unable to capture this redeclaration . I read that clang-tidy doesn't support Cross Translation Unit analysis (meaning it will run the check separately on each file).

**test1.cpp**

```
#include <cstdint>
namespace ns1
{
 static std::int32_t globalvariable = 0;
}
```

**test2.cpp**

```
#include <cstdint>
namespace ns1
{
 static std::int32_t globalvariable = 0;// Non-compliant- identifier reused
 // in ns1 namespace in test1.cpp
}
```

What are ways to workaround this problem?